# Rewrite lib Varien Image and its Adapters classes

Tags: overrides

I need to resize images to exact input dimensions (centered crop), so, I have add additional functions to `Varien_Image`, `Varien_Image_Adapter_Gd2`, `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`, and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image` classes.

I can easily rewrite catalog model and helper classes, but I don't know **how to rewrite Varien classes**. Currently, I make copies to local folder, it's not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

you `cannot  rewrite Varien classes and any lib classes`.
It is `magento feature`.. but  you will rewrite `Mage class`

so you can write `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image, and Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image`

Comment: I just found this question and the answers make me clearly understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105170/can-i-override-magento-varien-classes